# Proper Way of using search functionality in angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-services, angular12, angular13

Anyone please provide the proper way of using search functionality it should be showing results in the separate component & the user entered value could not be refreshed for further search.

[image]

This is the search Component (pic 1)

I have rendered the search component in another component named result

The result component is used for showing searched datas.

I need the user entered value after the search also to do further searches

the need like (pic 2)

[image]

The User entered Value is present in this pic 2

But in my case it is not there. i think it is refreshing when the result component loads.

I have passed data to result component using seperate service. now i have the data in two components

but how can i showed in the input box.

**search component .html**

```
<form [formGroup]="jobSearchForm" (ngSubmit)="jobSearchSubmit()">
            <div class="input-group job-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn search-panel">
                    <select class="form-select btn btn-default search-filter-btn" formControlName="versionId">
                        <option *ngFor="let version of versions" value="{{version.code}}">
                            {{version.Name}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <span class="input-group-btn search-lbl">
                    <span>
                        <fa-icon [icon]="briefcase" class="job-title-ico"></fa-icon>Job Title
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" formControlName="name" class="txt-large-search"
                    placeholder="Example: Banking, Insurance and other Financial Clerks">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="searchbtn-lg" type="submit">Search</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**result component .html**

```
<app-search-component></app-search-component>
```

**search component typescript**

```
jobSearchSubmit() {
    this.fetchedJobTitleName = this.jobSearchForm.controls.name.value;
    this.fetchedVersionId = this.jobSearchForm.controls.versionId.value;
    this.fetchedDatas = this.jobSearchForm.controls;
this.router.navigate(['search']);
}
```

Below code is used for passing data

**Service file**

```html
jobTitleMethod: Observable<any>;

  private jobTitleMethodData = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');

  constructor() {
    this.jobTitleMethod = this.jobTitleMethodData.asObservable();
  }

  jobMethod(data: any) {
    this.jobTitleMethodData.next(data);
  }
```

** search.ts**

```html
    var passingData: any = {
      Name: this.fetchedJobTitleName,
      versionCode: this.fetchedVersionId,
    };
    this.dataService.jobMethod(passingData);
```

**result.ts**

```html
this.dataService.jobTitleMethod.subscribe(
      (result) => {
        this.searchedParams = result;
        this.fetchedName = result.Name;
        this.fetchedVersionId = result.versionCode;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.warn(err);
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

when running

> this.router.navigate(['search']);

you will load the component associated with this route (i guess SearchComponent) and you will not be able to access this.fetchedJobTitleName, this.fetchedVersionId, etc.

You need to pass data while routing. See https://angular.io/guide/router#fetch-data-before-navigating

Comment: Sir I Have Updated The Codes Please Check This Out @Vincnet